# select column in hibernate does not work but * does

Tags: sql, hibernate, glassfish, entitymanager

I have this:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select * from TRANSAKTION",Transaktion.class);
List<Transaktion> trans = q.getResultList();
```

While this works, using a column name like id doesn't although it exists in database and generated entity class.

Other tables work fine it's just that one and with all columns. When I use `*` and `.getId()` it returns the correct id.

What could possibly be the problem?

**The error message is:**

```
SQL Exception: invalid column name
```

Comment: Can you add the full log output? There should be more detail in your `server.log`. This is a SQL exception, so almost certainly coming from your database and therefore **probably** not a problem with GlassFish or Hibernate.

Comment: I forgot to add: I executed the statement in my oracle sql developer and it worked. that's the weirdest part. unfortunately the server output is cut off and I don't know how to extend it

Comment: Did you tried with 

`select t.id from TRANSAKTION t`